# Background mode options for the killed application

Tags: ios, ios-background-mode

I know that changing the location (for example: entering the iBeacon region) can wake up "killed" applications in a moment. Remote notifications also can this too.

I am looking for another option that will wake up an application that is not currently working in the background.

I know that in the latest iPhones there is the possibility of reading the NFC tags through the system and opening applications using universal links.

Is there any other possibility (it can be hardware) that the system will wake the killed application in response to an event or the only options are NFC and change the region of location?

Comment: When you say “killed” do you mean apps that were suspended (and possibly later terminated/jettisoned) in the course of their normal lifecycle, or apps that the user manually “force quit”? These are two different scenarios. See [Understanding When Your App Gets Launched into the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7).

Comment: Thanks for comment. I mean app that user manually "force quit" so the app is in "not running state" and is not visible under app list after user press home button or swipe in newest devices.